# appState doesn't work on android (foreground, inactive, background)

Tags: react-native

1. How do I expect a user to close a react native (android platform) app. I'm already using appState but it doesn't work like on iOS. Is there any other way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It works the exact same way for me in Android & iOS.

```
const app_state = useRef(AppState.currentState);
const [app_state_visible, set_app_state_visible] = useState(app_state.current);

const app_state_subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change",    next_app_state => {
  set_app_state_visible(next_app_state)
})

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(app_state_visible)
  }, [app_state_visible])
```

console.log outputs the exact same in the exact same circumstances

````
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
  Android SDK:
    Android NDK: 22.1.7171670
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-native: ^0.68.3 => 0.68.3```
````